# How do I graph two columns not side by side?

Tags: windows-7, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

If I have data like so:

[image]

It's trivial to generate a graph/chart of **Item v Quantity**. However, how do I generate more complicated graphs/charts for

1. **Item v Items Cost**.
2. **Extended minus Items Cost** (essentially a profit margin), while also labeling based on **Item** name.
3. **Extended minus Items Cost** but also include **Tax**, essentially treating it as an Item/Items Cost.

My current solution involves creating dummy cells which reference the original entries. Is there a more correct way to graph any of these.

**EDIT:** I *just* figured out half of the solution. If, following this example, one drags and highlights cells `B18:B21`, then holds <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and again drags and highlights another column, for example, `D18:D21`, then question 1) is addressed.

If, however, one drags and highlights cells `B18:B21`, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Clicks Cells `D18`, `D19`, `D20`, and `D21`, then it does not work, even though the outcome seems to be the same.

Comment: I would recommend doing it the way that works.

Comment: @fixer1234 I thought your comment was stupid at first, but the learning curve on Pivot Tables is extremely steep. I will take your advice instead

Comment: I was borrowing from the ancient joke, "Doc, it hurts when I do this"; answer, "So don't do that.".  You said it works when you highlight the second column but not if you highlight the cells individually.  My answer was to highlight the column in the way that works.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [chart based on a pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Overview-of-PivotTable-and-PivotChart-reports-527c8fa3-02c0-445a-a2db-7794676bce96). In the pivot table, you can add [calculated fields](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Calculate-values-in-a-PivotTable-report-697406b6-ee20-4a39-acea-8128b5e904b8), such as / or show an item as a [percentage of a row or column](https://support.office.com/client/calculate-a-percentage-for-subtotals-6aa66bce-11c5-47f7-b6b6-0959b0b13a72).